# migrating code from gatsby to nextjs and now aws-sdk not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, next.js

I have the aws-sdk working in gatsby using a .env file to put a file to an S3 bucket and I am now migrating this to Nextjs however I am now getting the following error in Nextjs.

`Uncaught (in promise) CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

I can console log the s3 variable and see that the acccessid and key are set from the .env.local however the function to upload fails. Here is the code I am using in both Next and Gatsby.

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
})

// console.log('s3:', s3)

        
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    async upload() {
        const params = {
            Bucket: 'ntcasting',
            Key: `${project}-${basecampprojectid}/${surname}${firstname.charAt(0)}/${surname}${firstname.charAt(0)}-decform-${filedate}.${fileExtension}`,
            Body: selectedfiles,
            Tagging: `basecamp_project_id=${basecampprojectid}`,
        }

        await s3
            .upload(params)
            .on('httpUploadProgress', (progressEvent, response) => {
                const percent = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
                setuploadprog(percent)
                console.log(percent)
            })
            .promise()
```

I would be grateful for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try using the below code in next.config.js, this might help

```
 config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID),
        }
    }))
```